# console.log() not working as expected

Tags: javascript

Question: What would be consoled

```
var foo = 'outside';

function logIt() {
    console.log(foo);
    var foo = 'inside';
}

logIt();
```

Answer: `undefined`

Can someone explain why this is happening.

Comment: Because `foo` is also defined in the scope of `logIt` and hoisted to the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var` statements are hoisted.

There is only one variable accessed inside the function: The one created on the line `var foo = 'inside';`.

When you log the value of it, you do so before the assignment has taken place, so it is `undefined`.

You can't access the global variable of the same name from within the function because you have masked it by declaring a locally scoped variable of the same name.

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand this correctly myself - the function he's written is the same as:
    function logIt() { var foo; console.log(foo); foo = "inside"; }

Comment: @millerbr — For all practical purposes. Yes.

Answer (score 3):

```
var foo = 'outside';

function logIt() {
    var foo;
    console.log(foo);
    foo = 'inside';
}

logIt();
```

This is how the script is interpreted.So it gives `undefined`

This is called [top-hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

In this way re-declaration of `foo` is occur which set it to `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = 'outside';

function logIt() {
    console.log(window.foo);
    var foo = 'inside';
}
logIt();
```

logIt function assumes that `foo` is inside its scope. To use global variable you need to use `window.variable_name`